# Business Layer Call Business Layer or Call DAO directly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

In J2EE design, usually we have view layer, business layer and dao layer. In business layer, if we need some other data, shall we call the DAO directly or call the other data's business service?

Comment: This is a million dollar question. It depends on several factors, starting from how large the application is to the way it gets deployed and what type of DAO you are using. I think this is way too broad for SO and I recommend looking at some system design book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like this question, because I had to find the answer, and later convince the others... So my view, coming from experience on some projects is:

Business Layer should be built from Componenents (I would name them [`Facades`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)) which are responsible for some tasks. E.g.

- Validate Entity/Object before it is persisted (DAO is called) (kind of `Persist(entity)`)
- Or represent factory method `CreateNew()`, returning new objects with some basic business settings (pre-filled country, currency...)
- load some data via `Find(filter)`

And I could continue, but at the end, I would end up with Facades, which are really doing their tasks and are responsible for them. And that means that we have the answer.

> If there is already some *business object* (Facade) representing some specific task... other business componenets should use it. They should not reimplement it again.
>
> **To say it clearly explicitly**:
>
> - Other layers (presentation, scheduled job) should call only one Business API (service/facade)
> - This Business Service/Facade should do its job, and if needed it should call other Business Service(s)/Facade(s) and ask them to do their job.
> - That service should NOT call DAO if this is already implemented elsewhere.

So if there si some BL guy, ready to get data from DAO or pass (and validate) some other data into DAO ... we should use it...

At the end, we have [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles in place... and code becomes easy to maintain and extend. For example, if we know that there is only one `EmployeeFacade.Find(filter)`, it is easy to introduce AOP and be sure that all the results could be intercepted...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you are talking about call business layer from representation layer, my question is in business layer, shall we call other business service's method or call other's DAO method?

Comment: I tried to update my answer to express that more explicitly. Even if we are already on Business layer (one Service/Facade) we should definitely call othere Busienss Services/Layers if there are already such. We should not call DAO directly (if there is a service for it already). That is my message, my experience. Does it help? Is it more clear now?

Comment: Yes, Clear, Thanks. I will follow the same in my projects